# Auto-Increment correct formated serial number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, auto-increment

I am adding auto-increment serial number using CSS the issue here I am facing is it is working fine but the rows are not creating i.e its design is not built. Can anyone tell me what is I am doing wrong also I want to show 1..2..3 but it print me `11..22..33`? I am new to these technologies.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Objective No.</th>
      <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">My Performance Objective</th>
      <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Weightage<br>100%</th>
      <th colspan="5" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Standards of Performance</th>
      <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Outcome</th>
      <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr colspan="5">
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">1</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">2</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">3</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">4</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr colspan="5">
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Unsatisfactory</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Partially <br>Meets<br> Objectives</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Fully<br> Meets<br> Objectives</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Exceeds <br> Objectives</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Far <br>Exceeds<br> Objectives</th>
    </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">1</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">2</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">3</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Add Row" id="newobj">Add Objective</button>
  <button type="button" class="remove" value="Delete Row">Delete Objective</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
CSS:
body
{
  counter - reset: Count - Value;
    }
    table
    {
      border-collapse: separate;
    }
    tr td:first - child:before
    {
      counter-increment: Count - Value;
    content: "" counter(Count - Value);
    }

    jquery:
    $(document).add(function()
    {
      $("#newobj").click(function(){
    var addcontrol = "<tr>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td><input type='text' ></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td><input type='text' ></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td><input type='text' ></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td><input type='text' ></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td><input type='text' ></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td><input type='text' ></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td><input type='text' ></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td><input type='text' ></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "<td><input type='text' ></td>"
    addcontrol+ = "</tr>"
    $("table tbody").append(addcontrol);
    });
  //alert("Cannot add more than 8 objectives");
   $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();

  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check below code its working fine.

1. Your print result 11..22..33 because you already mentioned static numbers in markup td field and also you are incremented number through CSS So in this case you need to remove static numbers from your markup for accurate results.
2. For Design-build, you just add inline CSS in first td markup in your custom jquery file.

```js
$(document).add(function()
{
 $("#newobj").click(function(){
      var addcontrol="<tr>"
      addcontrol+="<td style='text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;'></td>"
           addcontrol+="<td><input type='text' ></td>"
           addcontrol+="<td><input type='text' ></td>"
           addcontrol+="<td><input type='text' ></td>"
           addcontrol+="<td><input type='text' ></td>"
           addcontrol+="<td><input type='text' ></td>"
           addcontrol+="<td><input type='text' ></td>"
           addcontrol+="<td><input type='text' ></td>"
           addcontrol+="<td><input type='text' ></td>"
           addcontrol+="<td><input type='text' ></td>"
           addcontrol+="</tr>"
   $("table tbody").append(addcontrol);
                   });
  //alert("Cannot add more than 8 objectives");
   $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();

});
});
```

```css
body
{
    counter-reset: Count-Value;     
}
table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
}
tr td:first-child:before
{
  counter-increment: Count-Value;   
  content: "" counter(Count-Value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Objective No.</th>
                          <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">My Performance Objective</th>
                          <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Weightage<br>100%</th>
                          <th colspan="5" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Standards of Performance</th>
                          <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Outcome</th>
                          <th rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Score</th>
                        </tr>
                         <tr colspan="5">
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">1</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">2</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">3</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">4</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">5</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr colspan="5">
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Unsatisfactory</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Partially <br>Meets<br> Objectives</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Fully<br> Meets<br> Objectives</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Exceeds <br> Objectives</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center; border:1px solid #e3ebf3;">Far <br>Exceeds<br> Objectives</th>
                        </tr>

                      </thead>
                      <tbody>

                        <tr>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;border:1px solid #e3ebf3;"><input type="text"  class="form-control"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                  </div>
                  <div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Add Row" id="newobj">Add Objective</button>
<button type="button" class="remove" value="Delete Row" >Delete Objective</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's really helpful